# Reading file containing Arabic language

Tags: c#, file, encoding, printing, character-encoding

I have a file that contains both Arabic and English word/letters/numbers. I'm trying to print the file using the code from [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). When I open the file in notepad, I see all the funny and unprintable chars.  When I save the same file as **Unicode** in **Save as...** file menu (notepad) and choosing Unicode, the file is displayed properly (I see Arabic letters, etc.).

When I open the same file in `notepad++` the only option that displays the file correctly is

**Menu->Encoding->Character set->Arabic**

With C#, I'm trying to read the file line by line and print it using

```
ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Red, leftMargin, yPos, _sf);
```

where `line` is the line from the file.  When the file is saved in right encode, everything prints out fine.  But when we have encoding issues, we get bunch of diamonds, question marks, etc.

Here are a few ways (from various sources) that I tried opening the file with right encoding (please let me know if one of them should work and I'll try again):

Attempt 1

```
var arabic = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
var bytes = arabic.GetBytes(line);
line = arabic.GetString(bytes);`
```

Attempt 2

```
streamToPrint = new StreamReader(this.filepath,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,true);
```

Attempt 3

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
line = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(utf8Bytes);`
```

None of them work.  Can someone kindly show me what changes I have to make to [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) code so that it will read the file and print it?

Comment: GetEncoding(1252) cannot be correct.  Try 1256, 864, 720.  Or send the file back, you don't want it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you.  I will give it a try and report back

Comment: @HansPassant 1256 (not 1252) was the solution.  If you provide an answer, it will be `accepted answer`.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   var arabic = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
```

That's not it, 1252 is the Windows codepage for Western Europe and the Americas.  Your next guess is [1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256), the default Windows codepage for Arabic.  Your next guess should be the legacy MS-Dos code pages, 864 and 720.

This kind of misery ought to inspire you to contact the company or programmer that created the file.  It is high time they update.  Best argument you can give them is that you are available now, probably won't be whenever they *need* to update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the BOM (Byte Order Mark, `U+FEFF`), which should be the first Unicode character in the file. If it's not found, It's either plain ASCI, UTF-8 without a byte order mark or something odd.

Read the first several octets of the file. The BOM is encoding differently for different encodings:

- hex `FE` `BB` `BF` indicates UTF-8. HOWEVER, for UTF-8, the BOM is optional, it being  meaningless, what with UTF-8 being an 8-bit encoding and all. If it's not found, it's no guarantee that the file is UTF-8, though. It could be plain ASCII or encoding with some other non-Unicode DBCS scheme.
- hex `FE` `FF` indicates UTF-16, big-endian (network byte order).
- hex `FF` `FE` indicates UTF-16, little-endian.
- hex `00` `00` `FE` `FF` indicates UTF-32, big-endian (network byte order).
- hex `FF` `FE` `00` `00` indicates UTF-32, little endian.
- etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding for more.

You might notice that this isn't fool-proof. A little-endian, UTF-16 encoding file would be hard to differentiate from a little-endian, UTF-32 encoded file...**if** it's first non-BOM Unicode character was an ascii `NUL` (U+0000).

Comment: Thank you.  Its a lot of good info.  I will go over it.  Was there a second part after ` it should indicate the file's encoding as follows:` or that colon meant to be a period?